# Symfony : An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine

I'm currently learning Symfony and Doctrine on Wamp, the problem is when i type the command

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

I have the following error :

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 110:

  An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver


In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  could not find driver


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  could not find driver
```

It's strange because i have my .env file with my DATABASE_URL correct :

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/csi_film4?serverVersion=5.7"
```

I also have on WAMP, the pdo_mysql extension ticked on the Wamp, and i've made sure that the extension is in my php.ini file.

But still, i have the error when i type the command to create a database...

I also did a php -m and php -i command on my command prompt but i don't see any pdo_mysql extensions in the php modules so i kknow these modules are missing but I have no idea how can I download them.

If you have any ideas how can I install the missing modules to my php on my Wamp server, I would be glad to have them !

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install MysQl, for Ubuntu just use
`sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

Comment: I still have the error, do I need to do the command in my Symfony project directory ?